# Kerastuner Randomsearch: TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'activation')

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, hyperparameters, conv-neural-network

Using Google Colab, I was trying to use Randomsearch from Kerastuner to find the best CNN for my use-case.

In my mind, everything should be set up properly but for some reason I always get

```
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'activation')
```

whenever declaring my RandomSearch.

Function to declare my model:

```
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models

def model_declaration(hp):
  cnn = models.Sequential([
    # Filtering & Pooling Layers
    layers.Conv2D(
        filters=hp.Int('filter1', min_value = 16, max_value = 128, step = 16), # Optimizing with filters from 16 to 128 in steps of 16 
        kernel_size = hp.Choice('kernel1', values=[3,6]), # Optimizing kernel size from 3 to 6
        activation ='relu',
        input_shape = (48,48,1) # always the same
        ),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=hp.Int('max_pooling_1', min_value = 2, max_value = 4, step = 16), activation = 'relu'),
    layers.Conv2D( 
        filters=hp.Int('filter2', min_value = 16, max_value = 128, step = 16 ), # Optimizing with filters from 16 to 128 in steps of 16 
        kernel_size = hp.Choice('kernel2', values=[3,6]), # Optimizing kernel size from 3 to 6
        activation = 'relu'),
    layers.Conv2D( 
        filters=hp.Int('filter3', min_value = 8, max_value = 256, step = 16 ), # Optimizing with filters from 16 to 128 in steps of 16 
        kernel_size = hp.Choice('kernel3', values=[3,6]), # Optimizing kernel size from 3 to 6
        activation = 'relu'
        ),
    layers.Flatten(), # Flattening
  ])

  for i in range(hp.Int('dense_layers', 2, 10)): 
      cnn.add(layers.Dense(units=hp.Int('dense_parameters'), min_value = 16, max_value = 128, step = 16), activation=hp.Choice(['relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid']))

  model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-1, 1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])),
                loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics = ['accuracy'])
  return model
```

And this is my declaration of my random search:

```
import kerastuner
from kerastuner import RandomSearch
from kerastuner.engine.hyperparameters import HyperParameter
random_search = RandomSearch(model_declaration, objective='val_accuracy', max_trials=5, directory='output', project_name='CNN best output')
```

Tensorflow version is 2.2.0-rc3
Kerastuner version is 1.0.1
Keras version is 2.3.0-tf

Thanks in advance for your help, I am really struggling with this as im fairly new to the subject.

Answer (score 1):

`MaxPooling2D` layer doesnt have `activation` parameter. Check [Keras Documentation](http://keras.io/layers/) too see layers specification.

Answer (score 0):

MaxPooling2D doesn't have an activation. Since MaxPooling is a layer that minimizes your data. It doesn't have an activation because it follows a certain algorithm that takes the pool size and takes the largest values for each area you selected.